# How to include an HTML/Javascript game into reactJS website

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I created a game using plain javascript and HTML with some JS libraries, and was wondering how to include the game inside my ReactJS website.

The game launches once the index.html file in its folder is opened. 
Is there any way to use react code to point to that index.html file so that the game opens?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `iframe` perhaps?

Comment: I actually just learned about this haha. I think i'll dangerouslysetInnerHTML iframe.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```html
<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/7159290/prateek-agrawal?tab=profile#user-card" style="width:100%; height:180px!important" />
```

Give the URL of **index.html** in **src** attribute.

Comment: Silly question, but where do I place the iframe code?